# Is a dead bat impure?

Tags: halacha, animals, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, birds

The Torah lists the ״עטלף״ which is generally translated to mean “a bat”, among the non kosher birds, but does that mean that it is considered a bird for every purpose, like when it comes to the laws of impurity of a carcass?

Comment: What wouldn't it?